Crear llenado de varios input partiendo de una lista de selección solo con php
Tengo una lista que trae valores de mi DB, el nombre de los clientes y quiero que al seleccionar uno me llene en los otros input con información como rif, dirección y números de teléfono, solo usando PHP.
Mi datalist lo tengo creado de esta manera:
<label for="NOMCLI" class="control-label"> Cliente: </label>
<input class="form-control" list="text" name="NOMCLI" id="NOMCLI" required>
<datalist id="text">
    <?php
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM tblsiscli";
    $result = $db->query($sql);
    while ($consulta = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        echo '<option value="' . $consulta['NOMCLI'] . '">' . '</option>';
    }
    ?>
</datalist>


Porqué solo PHP?? De poder se puede pero te estarías MEGA HIPER COMPLICANDO LA VIDA. Usa JS

y tambien le hace falta contenido al HTML de ejemplo ya que no veo ningun form, ademas que no veo que has intentado, mostrar el codigo con el que generas la lista no demuestra que has intentado para hacer lo que quieres ...

tampoco hacemos tareas o codigo para los usuarios, si estas intentando algo y no te funciona, agrega el codigo y el error para poder ayudarte

tambien te recomiendo hacer el [tour] del sitio

No he tratado de hacerlo con JS pero lo voy a intentar a ver como me resulta y les comento

Ya que en los comentarios abriste la posibilidad a usar javascript, aquí te expongo mi respuesta (que tal como mencionó @OCHOA era lo lógico)
Puedes utilizar atributos data-* para almacenar información en los option, luego al seleccionar un valor rescatas esos datos y los muestras en los inputs correspondientes.
Por ejemplo, crearé un data-nombre="Luigi", el código irá a buscar un elemento cuyo id sea nombre y le asignará Luigi a su value. Lo mismo con data-dir="siempre vida 123", ira a buscar un elemento cuyo id sea dir y le asigna el value. Tú puedes agregar los atributos que necesites y el código js es el mismo


document.getElementById("NOMCLI").addEventListener("input", e=>{
  const op = document.querySelector(`#text >option[value='${e.target.value}'`);
  
  //reseteamos los valores de los otros inputs
  document.querySelectorAll("input[data-targeted]").forEach(a=>a.value="");
  if(!op) return;
  
  
  //Asignamos los valores de los otros inputs
  for (let clave in op.dataset) {
    const el = document.getElementById(clave);
    if(!el) continue;
    el.value = op.dataset[clave];
  }
});
<input class="form-control" list="text" name="NOMCLI" id="NOMCLI" required>
<datalist id="text">
 <option value="AAAAAAA" data-nombre="Nombre_A" data-dir="dir_A"></option>
 <option value="BBBBBBB" data-nombre="Nombre_B" data-dir="dir_B"></option>
 <option value="CCCCCCC" data-nombre="Nombre_C" data-dir="dir_C"></option>
</datalist>

<input id="nombre" data-targeted>
<input id="dir" data-targeted>



